# Getting Javascript code to fire on a selection change on a DropDownList in ASP.Net

Tags: javascript, selectedindexchanged

I would like to add Javascript code to be fired when the selected index is changed on a dropdownlist in asp.net.

So, here is my DDL:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="comboReportTypes" runat="server" />
```

I would like to add something like this to the above DDL: onSelectionIndexChanged="MyJavascriptFuntion(this)"

So I'd like to end up with something like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="comboReportTypes" runat="server" onSelectionIndexChanged="MyJavascriptFuntion(this)" />
```

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance. I'm using ASP.Net 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add onchange event to it from the code .

Eg:
  DropDownList dlOption = new DropDownList();
 dlOption.Attributes.Add("onchange", "javascript:return functionname(this);");

Answer (score 0):

Using `jquery` you can easily achieve what you are trying to do

```
$('#comboReportTypes').change(function(){
//do whatever you need to.
});
```

**[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/k5Kur/)**

**Note:** Make sure you are using the correct `ID` for the `DropDownList` as `server` controls tend to change their `ID's` on rendering.